# Send with a form the highlighted text (jquery)

Tags: jquery

I want to live copy/paste the highlighted text in a textarea and then send it. How can I do that ? I have something to get the selected text in a popup :

```
if(!window.Kolich){
            Kolich = {};
        }

        Kolich.Selector = {};
        // getSelected() was borrowed from CodeToad at
        // http://www.codetoad.com/javascript_get_selected_text.asp
        Kolich.Selector.getSelected = function(){
            var t = '';
            if(window.getSelection){
                t = window.getSelection();
            }else if(document.getSelection){
                t = document.getSelection();
            }else if(document.selection){
                t = document.selection.createRange().text;
            }
            return t;
        }

        Kolich.Selector.mouseup = function(){
            var st = Kolich.Selector.getSelected();
            if(st!=''){
                alert("You selected:\n"+st);
            }
        }

        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(document).bind("mouseup", Kolich.Selector.mouseup);
        });
```

Thank you !

Comment: Send via AJAX or submit the form?

Comment: I want to live copy / paste the highlighted text in a textarea

Comment: I have a text and a textarea. If I select a part of the text, I want that part of the text to be transfered in the textarea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a jQuery plugin ([jQuery.selection](http://madapaja.github.io/jquery.selection/)) that could solve your problem.

This is the idea how you should incorporate it in your code:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(document).bind("mouseup", function() {
            var sel = $.selection('html');
            if (sel != '') {
                $('#yourTextAreaId').val(sel);
                $('#yourDivId').html(sel); // to fill the selection into the body of <div id="yourDivId"></div>
                // send the `sel` here
            }
        });
    });
```

**Working jsFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/Saran/2t4N4/

If you need help with submitting the form, let me know ;)

---

Furthermore, if you don't want to pick up the HTML markup elements (tags), just pickup the selection like this (w/o the `'html'` or `'get'` parameters):

```
var sel = $.selection();
```

**jsFiddle example:** http://jsfiddle.net/Saran/xWXvH/1/

Comment: Is it possible to copy that in a textarea (as previously resolved) AND in a div ?

Comment: is it possible to remove all html tag ? When I select a div, It will how <div>. Is there something to add for that ?

Comment: I've extended my answer with that info.